# Formatação do CommonMark sendo aplicada indevidamente dentro de bloco de código no SOpt

Tags: bug, formatação, syntax-highlighting, markdown

Reparei que algumas formatações do [CommonMark](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#setext-headings) estão sendo aplicadas em blocos de código no site principal, mas não aqui no Meta. Veja [como estava esta pergunta (antes de ser editada)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/470413/5) como referência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

O [@hkotsubo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) realizou alguns testes e compartilhou mais informações no [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365006/401803). Aparentemente esse problema ocorre quando a pergunta contém duas tags de linguagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta com cara de BUG mesmo, e dos graves. Creio nem ser BUG do markdown, mas sim de algum evento que esta sendo disparado "duas vezes", já que o problema não ocorre de primeira.

Comment: Eu consegui reproduzir o problema em uma situação bem específica: a pergunta deve ter pelo menos duas tags de linguagem (por isso não tem como acontecer no meta, pois tais tags não existem aqui). [Reportei isso no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365006/401803) <-- nesse link tem mais detalhes, vc pode aproveitar as imagens de lá para complementar a sua pergunta, se quiser :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado :) . Adicionei as informações. Se quiser editar (ou responder) quando receber alguma resposta concreta por lá, sinta-se à vontade.

Comment: Ah, acabei de ver que talvez o language-hint também pode ter a ver. Na pergunta em questão, é `text`, que pelo que vi é inválido. Mas se colocar uma linguagem válida, o problema não ocorre (atualizei a pergunta no meta.SE com isso)

Comment: @hkotsubo, eu que coloquei o `text` lá. Curiosamente, `lang-text` previne o _syntax highlighting_ padrão, mas somente `text` não. De todo modo, editei lá, adicionando `lang-none` e o "problema" já não é mais visível. Se é esperado ou não, não sei dizer. Mas pelos comentários do Metão, parece ser um comportamento esperado mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Resposta curta

É um *bug*, mas não da forma que imaginamos. De qualquer forma, pelo que vi, ainda não foi resolvido.

## Resposta longa

Eu [reportei este problema no Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365006/401803), e após respostas e comentários, descobri que é um *bug*, só que o problema não é a formatação em si.

Mas para entender melhor, precisamos relembrar como é feito o *syntax highlight* nos blocos de código. Você pode usar o triplo *backtick* (ou *code fence*), com ou sem o *language hint*:

````
```
Bloco de código sem language hint
```
````

````
```java
Bloco de código com language hint (no caso, "java")
```
````

Quando usamos um bloco de código sem *language hint*, o site usa as tags da pergunta para saber qual linguagem está sendo usada. No caso, há muitas tags que estão associadas a uma linguagem (a lista completa está [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/401803), na seção "*Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange*"), e só de colocar uma delas na pergunta, você já está dando a dica para o *highlighter*.

Quando a pergunta tem apenas uma tag de linguagem, todos os blocos de código sem *language hint* usarão o *syntax highlight* da linguagem correspondente à tag. Se algum bloco de código tiver um *language hint* válido (que pode ser diferente da linguagem correspondente à tag), aí a linguagem do *hint* é usada naquele bloco.

Lembrando que o *hint* pode ser tanto o nome da tag - desde que seja uma tag de linguagem - ou um dos códigos válidos indicados [no link acima](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/401803). Por exemplo, para JavaScript, você pode colocar `javascript` ou `js` (as tags de linguagem), ou um dos *hints* da lista (`lang-js`, `lang-javascript`, `lang-jsx`, `lang-mjs` e `lang-cjs`).

Mas quando há mais de uma tag de linguagem na pergunta e o bloco de código não tem *language hint* (ou tem um que é inválido), então o *highlighter* do site simplesmente tenta adivinhar qual é (provavelmente analisando o código), e pelo visto ele nem sempre acerta, e muitas vezes acaba usando um *highlight* de uma linguagem completamente nada a ver com as tags da pergunta. **Esse é o bug**, tanto que já foi sugerido usar somente as tags da pergunta como opções para o algoritmo de auto-detecção, em vez de deixá-lo usar uma linguagem completamente não-relacionada (ver [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354793/401803) e [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355852/401803) para mais detalhes).

---

#### Sobre o caso específico

No caso da pergunta em questão, aconteceu isso: ela tem duas tags de linguagem ([html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) e [css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)), e o trecho de código em questão tinha a *language hint* `text` ([antes de ser corrigido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/470413/5)), que não está na [lista já mencionada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/401803) (se fosse `lang-text`, por exemplo - ou qualquer outro válido - o problema não ocorreria).

Ou seja, como há mais de uma tag de linguagem e o *language hint* é inválido, então o *highlighter* tentou adivinhar, e no caso, ele concluiu que a "linguagem" usada naquele bloco é... Markdown!

É isso mesmo (eu confesso que fiquei surpreso, pois nunca tinha usado Markdown como "linguagem" em blocos de código). Então esse *highlight* é válido sim. Por exemplo, este bloco de código:

````
```lang-md
Título
---
texto normal, *itálico*, **negrito**, `código inline`, [link](http://www.google.com)

# Título

> quote
```
````

Repare que usei o *language hint* `lang-md`, que está na já citada lista de linguagens válidas (e que corresponde à linguagem Markdown). O bloco acima é renderizado assim:

[image: markdown language]

<sup>Só testei no *preview*, não salvei para não poluir o site.</sup>

Provavelmente foi o texto seguido de uma linha com hífens que fez com que o bloco fosse detectado como Markdown, e no caso, estas linhas foram reconhecidas como um título (repare na imagem acima que o *highlight* não é igual à renderização do Markdown feita nos posts).

Sendo assim, o *bug* não é que os blocos de código estejam sendo formatados como se fossem texto "normal" (como se estivessem no corpo da pergunta). O problema é que o *highlighter* está detectando a linguagem errada, quando há mais de uma tag de linguagem na pergunta. Neste caso só foi mais perceptível porque a linguagem detectada foi Markdown, e o *syntax highlight* dela acaba mudando também o tamanho da fonte, deixando mais evidente o problema (e isso já acontece há um tempo, mas quando a linguagem detectada é diferente do esperado, geralmente só muda algumas palavras-chave que não são coloridas corretamente, então fica mais difícil perceber).

No caso da pergunta em questão, [já foi resolvido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/470413/revisions): bastou mudar o *language hint* para um válido (no caso, foi `lang-none`, indicando para não fazer nenhum *highlight*).

Então o jeito - enquanto não arrumam o *bug* de auto-detecção - é sempre lembrar de colocar o *language hint* nos blocos de código quando tiver mais de uma tag de linguagem na pergunta.

Comment: Apesar da resposta não solucionar o bug, marquei como solução pois explica como contorná-lo :). Tenho minhas dúvidas se as sugestões de correção mencionadas (no meta.se) chegarão na lista de prioridades para serem implementadas um dia.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Os 2 links que indiquei do meta.SE estão como [status-deferred], que [segundo a wiki da tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-deferred/info), significa que "*will not be implemented or fixed in the near term*". Ou seja... :-/

Comment: Ainda não entendi porque o `text` não funcionou. Por exemplo, quando coloco o _hint_ `js` ele é inválido (já que só "`js`" não está listado)? O correto seria `lang-js`?

Comment: @LuizFelipe [Aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/401803) (na seção "_Language codes currently available on Stack Exchange_") tem todos os *language hints* válidos. Veja que `text` e `js` não estão lá, então são inválidos e por isso o *highlighter* acaba fazendo a auto-detecção. Os *hints* válidos são `lang-text` e `lang-js` (e outros, como `lang-javascript`, etc). Enfim, se o *hint* é inválido, ele tenta adivinhar. Se é válido, a respectiva linguagem é usada.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Só pra deixar mais correto (e como vc mesmo me disse), também dá pra usar nomes de tags em *language hints*, por isso `js` e `javascript` também seriam válidos (já no caso de `text`, acho que é inválido mesmo). Perdão pelo vacilo.